# Problema para ejecutar mi aplicación en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

resulta que estoy empezando a desarrollar aplicaciones con android studio pero tengo un problema al ejecutar mis programas, he usado el emulador de android studio, me carga todo bien pero al momento de abrir la aplicación me sale el mensaje "la aplicación se ha detenido", también he intentado instalar el archivo .apk en un celular, se instala correctamente pero al momento de ejecutarlo sale el mismo error.
alguien sabe que puede ser?

gracias por sus respuestas..

En el logcat me sale la siguiente excepcion:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.sergio.prueba/com.example.sergio.prueba.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an
> incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for
> VectorDrawableCompat.

Soy nuevo en esto asi que no se bien que significa y como corregir el error.

Me sucede lo mismo en todos los proyectos.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ActividadPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_principal);
    }
}
```

Comment: podrías poner el log de error, pero así tal cual, me parece que es problema de la versión mínima que especificas, que no es soportado por tu dispositivo, prueba en android studio crear proyecto en blanco y la versión mínima que te pide déjala 14, les das en compilar a ver si te muestra el mismo error

Comment: @pepe Si estas desarrollando en Android y no usas el LogCat estas "mirando a ciegas" , es importante el uso del LogCat para encontrar el error que causa tu aplicación se cierre. ¿Porque se cierra? no hay una respuesta para esto, pueden ser diversas causas.

Comment: Podrías pasar el código completo de MainActivity de java para revisarlo? en esa parte debería estar el problema, trata de usar el depurador para encontrar el código mas rápido.

Comment: Añade tu gradle donde se especifica la versión mínima y tu dispositivo que itnentas ejecutarlo que versión hay en el?

Comment: y versión del jdk "java"

Comment: Lo pudiste resolver? a mí también me pasa

Answer (score 1):

Posible solución:
Descargar Android studio 2.1.2 y el JDK Java 8 "1.8"

Configuración de Android studio

`File->Settings` en el cuadro de búsqueda escribir `gradle`

Nos debe situar en: `Build, Execution, Deployement -> Build Tools-> Gradle`

Seleccionar `Use default gradler wrapper (recomended)`

> Gradle se actualizará, puede tardar algunos minutos

**Comprobar que se usa JDK versión 8**

`File->Project Structure` sección `SDK Location`

en JDK Location debe ser algo parecido a:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92`

pulsar sobre la sección `app` y pestaña `Propieties` en `Buil Tools versión`, seleccionar `24.0.0` y aceptar.

También se puede realizar modificando directamente el `app.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.webserveis.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que me ha salido ese error en el que se detiene la aplicación ha sido por algún error en el código.

Repasa el código, te recomiendo que hagas un nuevo proyecto y lo ejecutes a ver si compila todo.

Si el nuevo proyecto te ejecuta bien, ves añadiendo partes de la otra aplicación mientras ejecutas el proyecto, hasta que encuentres el código que te genera dicho error.

Para poder dar una solución más específica necesitamos que adjuntes como mínimo el error de la consola, y algo de código.

Comment: Si solo es sugerencia o dudas de la pregunta se debe de "comentar" y no publicarlas como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve este mismo problema y hago referencia al link del issue que me ayudo a resolverlo!  [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214182) donde te dicen que

> Desde la versión 2.0 del `gradle` los recursos de las bibliotecas
>   nunca se *"rasterizan"* por lo tanto esto nunca sucederá.

```
buildscript {
...
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
 }
}
```

Intenta siempre tener la ultima versión.

Answer (score 0):

La solución para esto es para actualizar su Gradle siguiendo este enlace oficial. Plugin para Android Gradle notas de la versión.

```
buildscript {

  dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez se solucione con añadir soporte de imágenes de vector, [extraído de aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35633411/3464919).

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```