# problema al ejecutar apk en celular

Tags: android, android-studio

Verán pues tengo el siguiente código y recién comienzo en esto de android, bueno pues tengo un problema al ejecutar la app en mi celular (dice que se ha cerrado inesperadamente), lo cual no logro encontrar el error ya que en el emulador de mi laptop corre bien, tengo los archivos agregados, ¿alguna idea?

[image: adjunto foto]

```
package mx.edu.itoaxaca.oraciones;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Palabras extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<Object> pistas;
    private MediaPlayer reprod;
    private String texto;
    private TextView ora;
    private boolean bandSujeto,bandAd,bandAc,bandLugar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_palabras);
        reprod=null;
        pistas=new ArrayList<Object>();
        ora=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.oracion);
        bandSujeto=false;
        bandAc=false;
        bandLugar=false;
        bandAd=false;
        texto="";
    }

    public void reproducir(View eve){
        ora.setText("");
        texto="";
        switch (eve.getId()){
            case R.id.dog:
                pistas.add(R.raw.perro);
                bandSujeto=true;
                texto+="El perro ";
                //play(R.raw.perro);
                break;
            case R.id.lion:
                pistas.add(R.raw.leon);
                bandSujeto=true;
                texto+="El león ";
                //play(R.raw.leon);
                break;
            case R.id.elephant:
                pistas.add(R.raw.elefante);
                bandSujeto=true;
                texto+="El elefante ";
                //play(R.raw.elefante);
                break;
            case R.id.parrow:
                pistas.add(R.raw.guacamaya);
                bandSujeto=true;
                texto+="La guacamaya ";
                //play(R.raw.guacamaya);
                break;
        }
    }
    public void adjetivo(View eve){
        if(bandSujeto==false){
            Toast to= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Seleccione un Sujeto primero!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            to.show();
        }else{
            switch (eve.getId()){
                case R.id.man:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.manchas);
                    bandAd=true;
                    texto+="con manchas ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
                case R.id.feroz:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.feroz);
                    bandAd=true;
                    texto+="feroz ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
                case R.id.afric:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.africano);
                    bandAd=true;
                    texto+="africano ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
                case R.id.ruidosa:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.ruidosa);
                    bandAd=true;
                    texto+="ruidosa ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    public void accion(View eve){
        if(bandAd==false){
            Toast to= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Seleccione un adjetivo primero!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            to.show();
        }else{
            switch (eve.getId()){
                case R.id.eat:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.come);
                    bandAc=true;
                    texto+="come ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;

                case R.id.caza:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.caza);
                    bandAc=true;
                    texto+="caza ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
                case R.id.bania:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.bana);
                    bandAc=true;
                    texto+="se baña ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
                case R.id.sing:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.canta);
                    bandAc=true;
                    texto+="canta ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void lugar(View eve){
        if(bandAc==false){
            Toast to= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Seleccione una accion primero!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            to.show();
        }else{
            switch (eve.getId()){
                case R.id.house:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.casa);
                    bandAd=true;
                    texto+="en casa ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
                case R.id.origen:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.sabana);
                    bandAd=true;
                    texto+="en la sabana ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
                case R.id.lago:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.lago);
                    bandAd=true;
                    texto+="en el lago ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;
                case R.id.three:
                    pistas.add(R.raw.arbol);
                    bandAd=true;
                    texto+="en el arbol ";
                    //play(R.raw.perro);
                    break;


            }
        }
    }


    public void play(View eve){
        ora.setText(texto);
        if(reprod!=null){
            stopPlaying();
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Iterator<Object> it=pistas.iterator();
                try {
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        //Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Object num = it.next();
                        reprod = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), (int) num);

                        reprod.start();
                        Thread.sleep(1050);


                    }

                  pistas.clear();

                }catch(Exception e){;}
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public void rest(View eve){
        if(reprod!=null){
        reprod.release();
        reprod = null;}
        texto="";
        ora.setText("");
        pistas.clear();
        bandAc=false;
        bandAd=false;
        bandSujeto=false;
        bandLugar=false;
    }
    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (reprod != null) {
            reprod.stop();
            reprod.release();
            reprod = null;
        }
    }
    public void vacia(){
        if(reprod.isPlaying())
        pistas.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya activaste USB Debbuging Mode (Depuración por USB)  depuración remota en tu teléfono?

Comment: si en realidad me dice que se ha cerrado inesperadamente la app

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19580/problema-para-ejecutar-mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-en-android-studio

Comment: Mira a ver que te dice el logcat en el android monitor

Comment: Necesitamos ver el log o algo como dice @AlbertoMartínez de logcat

Comment: añadi como respuesta el resultado del logcat

Comment: @AndyM.Moreno  
es mejor que edites tu pregunta y añadas esa información

Comment: @AndyM.Moreno lo que comenta UserNameYo puede ayudar, pero te sugiero trates de optimizar las imagenes, revisa su respuesta con la actualización.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este error es consecuencia de que se cargan demasiadas imágenes o las imagenes son muy grandes:

Prueba añadiendo android:largeHeap="true" en tu `AndroidManifest`, lo que realiza es tratar de aumentar la memoria disponible para tu aplicación:

> android:largeHeap="true"

Debería quedar algo así:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Pero es importante optimizar las imagenes, te sugiero revises esta respuesta con tips para optimizar tus imágenes:

[buena Resolución de una imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%C3%B3n-de-una-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror/6359#6359)

Comment: muchas gracias !!

Comment: eso resolvió el problema, solo una duda, este error es común o por la forma en que se desarrolla una app, si es asi de que forma puede ser la mas adecuada para evitar tanta saturación de memoria, en mi celular ya lo ejecuta pero no corre fluido como en el emulador

Comment: Es un problema muy común, sí, ocurre cuando hay muchas imágenes en una aplicación. No olvides dar +1 si la respuesta le soluciono su problema :) @AndyM.Moreno

Comment: @UserNameYo podrias agregar especificamente porque se produce el problema, tambien que hace el parametro que dijiste que agregara ya que para futuros errores de otros usuarios probablemente sea importante saber PORQUE falla y no SOLO resolverlo. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema que agregas es un error `OutOfMemoryError`, es un problema muy comun y es un problema de la maquina virtual de java (JVM) cuando falta espacio para asignar un objeto o bien el recolector no ha liberado espacio basura. Tambien puede deberse a que tu aplicación contiene muchos archivos (imagenes, audios) como es en tu caso.

Agregar a tu `AndroidManifest` el parametro `android:largeHeap="true"` puede ser una solución, pero en la misma documentación indican que no es lo recomendable :

> La mayoria de las aplicaciones no deberian necesitar de este
>   parametro y en su lugar, deberian centrarse en liberar o reducir el
>   uso total de memoria para mejorar el rendimiento. Si se habilita este parametro no se garantiza el aumento fijo de la memoria disponible, debido a que algunos dispositivos limitan su memoria total.